# Change the Icon in Phonegap

Tags: ios5, cordova, icons

Hi there I'm really having troubles changing the Icon in my Phonegap-App (Cordova 2.5.0)
I put my icons into the folder Projectname/Ressources/Icons.
Then I removed the icons there

But where in the Project do I change the name of the Icon.
I'm getting an error, that the icon-72.png isn't found - but I have no idea where to change the name of the icon from icon-72.png to myicon.png

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove old icon references. To do that :

In your Xcode project settings to go Build Phases and find in Copy Bundle Resources these old icon references. Delete them. Then, in your nav bar, go to Product>Clean.

Now build your project. It should work.